# Replace doesn't work in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

I tried following in Sybase

```
SELECT ChrgAmt, REPLACE(convert(varchar(255),ChrgAmt), '.', '') AS Result
FROM PaymentSummary
```

But it gives below error in isql

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'REPLACE'.
```

What could be the possible reason

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one decimal point, you can do it this way:

```
   stuff(convert(varchar(255), chrgamt),
         charindex('.', ChrgAmt),
         1, NULL)
```

Comment: In fact it returns `blank ` for my input data for ChrgAmt i.e. `270.00 `. The data is initially in `numeric(9,2) `

Comment: It did work with this, `stuff(convert(varchar(255), ChrgAmt), charindex('.', convert(varchar(255), ChrgAmt)), 1, NULL) `. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

On Sybase ASE there is [str_replace](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks214.htm) funciotn

```
SELECT ChrgAmt, str_replace(convert(varchar(255),ChrgAmt), '.', '') AS Result
FROM PaymentSummary
```

you can also use [cast](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks116.htm) instead of `convert` as below

```
SELECT ChrgAmt, str_replace(cast(ChrgAmt as varchar(255)), '.', '') AS Result
FROM PaymentSummary
```

Comment: Thanks Parado, Here also needs to use `NULL ` instead for `'' ` for me. Otherwise it will give space there

Comment: @ManthreePeiris Do you want to to remove a dot and space?

Comment: My requirement was to remove the decimal point. Sorry may be its confusing at your end

Answer (score 1):

Sybase ASE uses str_replace() instead of replace()

Answer (score 0):

the problem of your query is the varchar(255), remove the 255 then should be fine

```
SELECT ChrgAmt, REPLACE(convert(varchar,ChrgAmt), '.', '') AS Result
FROM PaymentSummary
```

the best one i will recommended nvarchar instead of varchar , cheer

Comment: Thanks for your update. Even without `255 ` it does give the same results. As I mentioned I am on `Sybase `

Answer (score 0):

This works in **"Ase"**:

```
select
  ChrgAmt
  , str_replace(convert(varchar(255),ChrgAmt), '.', null) as Result
from
  PaymentSummary
```